# Voting versus flagging exact duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Should I vote to close exact duplicates or flag them for mod attention or both?

I just voted to close a question that was asking about resuming an enumeration. We've had this before and there is nothing extra to the question. In this case, is it worth flagging for mod attention or not?

Answer (score 5):

I'd say both seem acceptable. Voting to close is good as the idea is that the community as a whole should deal with issues, and that means high-rep users need to vote. Flagging for the mods is also good as it makes sure we are aware of any issues. If there is 'nothing to see here' then dismissing a mod flag is not much work :-)

Comment: I agree. @Seamus: Note if you flag really important close request you guarantee their fast procession by a moderator. Also note that the close votes are visible to the moderators and 10k rep users beside the 'close' link. There is also a list of question with close votes. However, I rarely have a look on them. I just browse most of the question anyway.

Comment: @Martin: Actually you only need 250rep to see close votes: http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/view-close-votes

Comment: @Caramdir: Ok, I confused that with the mod tools then.